# Ruby decode string

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8

In Ruby how can I get:

`"b\x81rger"` by providing the string `"bürger"`.

I need to print special characters to a Zebra printer, I can see that `"b\x81rger"` prints `"bürger"`, but sending `"bürger"` does not print the correct character.

Comment: You're having issues with German characters only ? You need a method to translate "bürger" into "b\x81rger" and other words that have special characters ?

Comment: I will have problems with special characters in general, å,ä,ü,á, etc.

Comment: Ä = \\x8e, ä = \\x84, Ö = \\x99, ö = \\x94, Ü = \\x9a, ü = \\x81, ß = \\xe1 Here's the table for german characters, unfortunately I can not find out the rest of the table that your printer is using. I hope someone else with more knowledge in encoding/decoding can help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Viktor. Yep in case I can't find some usable method I guess I could do the substitution myself. Though I hope there's a general method for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out it’s **`CP850`**.

**Proper solution (Ruby 2.5+)**

Normalize the unicode string and then encode it into `CP850`:

```
"bürger".unicode_normalize(:nfc).encode(Encoding::CP850)
#⇒ "b\x81rger"
```

Works for both special characters and combined diacritics.

**Fallback solution (Ruby 2.5-)**

Encode and pray it’s a composed umlaut:

```
"bürger".encode(Encoding::CP850)
#⇒ "b\x81rger"
```

Comment: Awesome! This solves the issue with the printer. Thanks!